# How do I extract these values from a Ruby array

Tags: ruby

I'm debugging some Ruby code that uses the AWS SDK to extract EC2 tags:

```rb
         resource = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(client: client)

         resource.instances({filters: fetch(:ec2_filters)}).each do |instance|
           puts "DEBUG: #{instance.tags}"
           app_tag = instance.tags.select { |t| t.key == 'application' }.pop.value
```

We recently updated the `jmespath` dependency to pick up [this change](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.rb/compare/v1.6.0...v1.6.1).

**BEFORE** updating:

```
DEBUG: [#<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="application", value="api">, #<struct Aws::EC2::Types::Tag key="environment", value="production">]
```

**AFTER** updating `jmespath`

```
DEBUG: [{:key=>"application", :value=>"api"}, {:key=>"environment", :value=>"production"}]
```

The `.select { |t| t.key == 'application' }.` now throws an error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

Can anyone advise how to parse the new response format? (i.e. `[{:key=>"application", :value=>"api"}...`)

**UPDATE 1**

```rb
# This finds the correct item, but I'm not sure how to extract ':value'
puts "DEBUG: #{instance.tags.select { |t| t[:key] == 'application' }}"


DEBUG: [{:key=>"application", :value=>"api"}]
```

**UPDATE 2**

This works:

```rb
puts "DEBUG: #{instance.tags.select { |t| t[:key] == 'application' }[0][:value]}"

DEBUG: api
```

Comment: Don't know the library, but it looks like an ordinary Ruby hash. Have you tried `t[:key] == 'application'`?

Comment: a slightly smaller version of your update: `instance.tags.find{|t| t[:key] == 'application' }[:value]` using `#find` instead of `#select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the change the value of `instance.tags` used to be a struct, where you can access the key attribute by using dot notation, now you have a hash so you can use `:[]` instead, e.g:

```
Struct.new(:key).new('hej').key # "hej"
({ key: 'hej' })[:key]          # "hej"
```

Comment: Thankyou. Do you know if there is a cleaner way to get the value than: `instance.tags.select { |t| t[:key] == 'application' }[0][:value]`

Comment: Maybe you could use `find` instead of `select`, because you need only the first element in the resulting array if it exists, perhaps `(instance.tags.find { |t| t[:key] == 'application' } || {})[:value]` (`(... || {})` is just to avoid doing a nil check)